Can two different spin structures on a manifold induce the same spin$^c$ structure?
Let $(M,g)$ be an oriented Riemannian $n$-manifold with transition functions $g_{\alpha\beta}:U_{\alpha \beta}\to SO(n)$.
A spin structure on $M$ is a lift of $g_{\alpha\beta}$'s to functions $\tilde{g}_{\alpha \beta}:U_{\alpha \beta}\to \text{Spin}(n)$ that satisfy the cocylce condition. Since there is a natural map $\text{Spin}(n)\to \text{Spin}^c(n)$, a spin structure canonically induces a spin$^c$ structure.
Suppose $M$ has two different spin structures. Can the induced two spin$^c$ structures be the same?
Since the number of spin structures are in bijection with $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)$ and the number of spin$^c$ structures are in bijection with $H^2(M;\Bbb Z)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure#Obstruction_and_classification and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_structure#Classification), this would be true for spin manifolds with, for example, $H^1(M;\Bbb Z_2)\neq 0$ and $H^2(M;\Bbb Z)=0$. However I am looking for a criterion to check whether two spin structures give the same spin$^c$ structures or not, using characteristic classes, etc.

Spin structures naturally form a torsor over $H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}/2)$; in particular this means that the "difference" of two spin structures is an element of $H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}/2)$ on the nose. Similarly the "difference" between two spin-c structures is an element of $H^2(M, \mathbb{Z})$ on the nose (although I don't know how to calculate either of these things). The map between these two things describing how the difference behaves when you complexify a spin structure is a Bockstein homomorphism
$$\beta : H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}/2) \to H^2(M, \mathbb{Z})$$
which can be thought of geometrically as the complexification map from real to complex line bundles, or algebraically as coming from a long exact sequence induced by the short exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{2} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 0$.
This algebraic description shows that the kernel of the Bockstein homomorphism is given by the image of the reduction $\bmod 2$ map $H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^1(M, \mathbb{Z}_2)$, and in particular can be nonzero; whenever this kernel is nonzero there are two spin structures inducing the same spin-c structure. The universal coefficient theorem implies that the reduction $\bmod 2$ map is actually surjective whenever $H_1(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is free, and if it's surjective then we actually have $\beta = 0$ identically. For example this happens if $M = T^2$ is a torus, even though $H^1(T^2, \mathbb{Z}/2)$ and $H^2(T^2, \mathbb{Z})$ are both nonzero. In this case we can also see that the Bockstein must be zero because $H^2(T^2, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ doesn't have any $2$-torsion.
